# What does the set describe?

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

Let $C$ be the set of all points on the unit circle. We are given the following set \begin{equation*}A:=\left \{5v \mid v\in C\right \} \end{equation*}

$v$ is of the form $(x,y)$ for which $x^2+y^2=1$, or not?

Then $5v$ is $(5x,5y)$. Then should it satisfy the equation $(5x)^2+(5y)^2=1$ ?

Comment: "*on* the unit circle" or "*in* the unit circle"?

Comment: We are given the following set [...] $v$ is of the form $(x,y)$ for which $x^2+y^2=1$, or not?"  Sorry, but that sentence doesn't parse! "or not" **what**?

Comment: as @EricTowers asked, is it in the unit circle or on the unit circle? if 'in' then $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, then ; if 'on' then it's in the way you described it. in either ways, the equation/inequality about the group $A$ suppose to state $5$ instead of $1$

Comment: "Menge aller Punkte auf dem Einheitskreis" is the original text, so it is*on*, or not? @EricTowers

Comment: @MaryStar : My German is imperfect.  I read that as "on the unit circle", but this may be an idiom unfamiliar to me.  I defer to the better judgment of native speakers (if any will chime in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with "on the unit circle", \begin{align*}
C &= \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}  \\
A &= \{5v : v \in C \}  \\
    &= \{5(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : (x,y) \in C \}  \\
    &= \{5(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}  \\
    &= \{(5x,5y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}  \\
    &= \{(5x,5y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \frac{(5x)^2}{5^2} + \frac{(5y)^2}{5^2} = 1 \}  \\
    &= \{(5x,5y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : (5x)^2 + (5y)^2 = 25 \}  \\
    &= \{(\hat{x},\hat{y}) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \hat{x}^2 + \hat{y}^2 = 5^2 \}  \text{,}  \\
\end{align*}
which is the circle of radius $5$.

Comment: And if not both $x$ and $y$ would be multiplied by the same number would we do the same? I mean if we have for example the set $S=\{(3x, 5y)\}$

Comment: In that case we would have \begin{align*}
B&:=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}3x \\ 5y\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}\in C\right \}  \\
    &= \left \{\begin{pmatrix}3x \\ 5y\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \right \}  \\
    &= \left \{\begin{pmatrix}3x \\ 5y\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2  : \frac{(3x)^2}{3^2} + \frac{(5y)^2}{5^2} = 1 \right \}  \\
    &= \{(\hat{x},\hat{y}) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \frac{\hat{x}^2}{9} + \frac{\hat{y}^2}{25} = 1^2 \}  \text{,}  \\
\end{align*} How would we continue?

Comment: @MaryStar recognize that you have written the equation of an ellipse

Comment: Oh yes! The equation of the circle and the ellipse are the equations that have as set of solutions the sets $A$ and $B$ respectively, or not?